# Progressbar error

Tags: android, progressdialog

i want to put a progress bar while fetching data on cloud

Here's my code:

```
public void progressBar() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
                  "dialog message", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run()
                  {
                    // do the thing that takes a long time
                      displayView();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run()
                      {
                        progress.dismiss();
                      }
                    });
                  }
                }).start();
    }
```

and my displayView(); method

Here is the code:

```
public void displayView() {

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_format, 
                R.id.item_list,handler.getRetrieveData());
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position ,
                    long id) {

                intent = new Intent(TechiesActivity.this,ItemInfoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);              
            }
        });

    }
```

i'm getting this kind of error

error from the logcat:

```
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:607)
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:633)
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2505)
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5139)
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1011)
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:493)
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:422)
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.shop.browser.TechiesActivity.displayView(TechiesActivity.java:111)
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.shop.browser.TechiesActivity$1.run(TechiesActivity.java:75)
02-25 14:39:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654): Activity com.shop.browser.TechiesActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f30660 that was originally added here
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.shop.browser.TechiesActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f30660 that was originally added here
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at com.shop.browser.TechiesActivity.progressBar(TechiesActivity.java:68)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at com.shop.browser.TechiesActivity.onClick(TechiesActivity.java:198)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-25 14:39:51.629: E/WindowManager(1654):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know why i'm getting an error, I'm new to android programming please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the `DisplayView` method inside the `runOnUiThread` method and it should be fine

```
public void progressBar() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "dialog title",
                  "dialog message", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run()
                  {
                    // do the thing that takes a long time
                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run()
                      {
                        displayView();                      
                        progress.dismiss();
                      }
                    });
                  }
                }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform any `UI` update from worker / background Thread. so your method

```
displayView();
```

you need to call it in `runOnUiThread()`.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      displayView();
      progress.dismiss();
   }
});
```